The 'technical' and 'configuration' tags
I believe these two are meta tags. If they're not, then I don't know how they're supposed to be used.
For (technical), it's got to be a technical question about something. Whatever it is, that's the tag that should be used. Does this just mean a hard question?
For (configuration), it's got to be the configuration of something, and again, that's the tag that should be used.
These tags, at least as I understand them, neither clarify a question nor indicate the area of expertise a question requires to answer. Those are the two things tags are supposed to do.

I agree. They are too broad and not really useful.

A quick summary about the different usages of a problematic tag would be useful here.

I just put in an edit request to remove technical from the only question with that tag.

configuration is still or again around, and it should be removed for the reasons mentioned by David Schwartz.
